# How to load a full html page in a box within a full html page

Tags: html, iframe, frame

I have an HTTP Post Return that includes a whole HTML page that I'm trying to display in a box (or contained area) within another page.  I've thought about saving it as a temp doc then redisplaying via a Frame or iFrame... but that seems convoluted.  I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Here is an example of the HTML I'm trying to display within another HTML page without having to save it to a file on the server first.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head></head>

<script language="javascript">

function openWin(page,win_width,win_height){

try {popup_window.close();} catch(e){}if ( page.indexOf("mailto") == -1 ) {

var options ="scrollbars=yes, width=" + win_width + ", height=" + win_height;

var win = window.open(page, 'MyWin', options);

if (window.focus) { win.focus() }}}

</script>



<body bgcolor="#E5E5E5">

<table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">Thank You</td>

</tr>

<tr><td height="10px;"></td></tr>

<tr>

<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;">Representatives from the following companies will be contacting you soon.</td>

</tr>

<tr><td height="10px;"></td></tr>

<tr><td><table id="someTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td>

<table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td align="center">

<img src="http://someurl.com/somepic.gif" border="0" alt="TEXT" title="TEXT"/>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding-top:5px;">

TEXT

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top" align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding-top:5px;">

<a href="javascript:openWin('http://someurl.jsp','517','460');" title="More Information">More Information</a>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

<td>

<table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td align="center">

<img src="http://someurl.com/somepic.gif" border="0" alt="TEXT" title="TEXT"/>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding-top:5px;">

TEXT

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top" align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding-top:5px;">

<a href="javascript:openWin('http://someurl.jsp','517','460');" title="More Information">More Information</a>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

<td>

<table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td align="center">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="140px;"><tr><td width="140px;"><img src="http://someurl.com/somepic.gif" border="0" alt="TEXT" title="TEXT"/></td></tr></table>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding-top:5px;">

Text

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td valign="top" align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding-top:5px;">

<a href="javascript:openWin('http://someurl.jsp','517','460');" title="More Information">More Information</a>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

<tr><td height="10px;"></td></tr>

</table></td></tr></table>

<table style="display:none"><tr><td><input type="hidden" id="XXDataCaptureKey" value="12345" /><input type="hidden" id="DATA" value="data" /></td><tr></table>


 <!-- ******** XX RESPONSE ********* 
* KEY: 12345 
* DATA: data 
* STATUS: SUCCESS
***************** 
--> 


</body></html>
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: You wouldn't have to save the file, you'd just echo it dynamically from the same script, like `<iframe src="thispage.aspx/innerpage">` or something. But there is a better solution, just maybe not quite as simple depending on your purpose.

Comment: How would you go about echoing it dynamically?

Comment: Get the URL of the page using whatever server-side language you use, and get the part after the `.aspx` (or `.php` or `.cgi` or whatever) and echo contents based on that part.

Comment: Thanks but, All of the code above (in the original question) IS the return... it's not $_GET variables.  Does that make sense.?.?  I must not be explaining it very well.  The "Server Response" IS the above code (a simple page) and it's dynamic and I need to display it within a "box" on the HTML page itself.

Comment: And I'm saying, to implement that, you *will* need to split up the logic, if only to two requests - that's the point of an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

you could serve it up in an <object src="index.html"> element

Comment: That's another external page that I would have to save first, if I'm understanding you correctly.  Thanks for the answer.